# Function takes wrong values from pointers c++ and returns wrong answer

Tags: c++

I've just started learning programming, and got some troubles. Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Create a new class with a constructor;
2. Write two numbers from user into a class objects;
3. Use this class' function to get a sum of two numbers;

But for some reason class function takes some strange numbers instead of class objects (I'm checking them along the road).

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class math_function {
public:
    string function_string;
    double function_result;
};

class binary_operation : public math_function {
public:
    double* argument_1;
    double* argument_2;
};

class sum : public binary_operation {
public:
    sum(double arg1, double arg2) {
        this->argument_1 = &arg1;
        this->argument_2 = &arg2;
        cout << *this->argument_1 << " INSIDE CONSTR " << *this->argument_2 << "\n";
    }

    double evaluate() {
        cout << *this->argument_1 << " pointers " << *this->argument_2 << "\n";
        this -> function_result = *this->argument_1 + *this->argument_2;
        return function_result;
    }
};

int main(int argc, string argv)
{
    cout << "enter two nubmers\n";
    double arg1, arg2;
    std::cin >> arg1;
    std::cin >> arg2;
    sum* sum1 = new sum(arg1, arg2);
    double result = sum1->evaluate();
    cout << "\n" << result;
    system("Pause");
}
```

And here's the output from the console:

```
enter two numbers
29
13
29 INSIDE CONSTR 13
-9.25596e+61 pointers 1.23419e-305
-9.25596e+61
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"What am I doing wrong?"_ Not to inspect your code  line by line using the debugger.

Comment: `sum(double arg1, double arg2) ` The addresses of those parameters go out of scope after the constructor function is left. Why do you take pointers of these at all there?

Comment: I use pointer because later I will need to point to another function result and not to some known number. And also isn't the addresses are written to a binary_operation argument_1 and 2 and are staying there?

Comment: Use references instead then.

Comment: @АлександрКоржев The addresses are staying there, what they are pointing to isn't. That's the problem. There's no need to use pointers for this assignment or the assignment you have in the future. Do things the easy way.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
this->argument_1 = &arg1;       // NO
```

is kind of the opposite of what you want to do. You are setting the pointer member to the adress of `arg1` which is local to the constructor. At the time you try to print the value, `arg1` is long gone. If anything, you want

```
*(this->argument_1) = arg1;     // still NO
```

this would assign the value of `arg1` to the `double` `argument_1` is pointing to. However, you never allocated a `double`, so `argument_1` is not pointing to a double. Dereferencing an invalid pointer is undefined behaviour!

Simply dont use pointers. And better use the initializer list...

```
struct binary_operation : public math_function {
    double argument_1;
    double argument_2;
    binary_operatotion(double arg1,double arg2) : argument_1(arg1),argument_2(arg2) {}
};

struct sum : public binary_operation {
    sum(double arg1, double arg2) : binary_operation(arg1,arg2) {}
};
```

Comment: Simply don't use pointers. Should be the first thing beginners learn about C++.

Comment: @john well, pointers are good for something, but if you dont need that "something" its  pointless to use pointers

Answer (score 0):

you are storing in argument1 and 2 the address of the two parameters passed (by value) to the constructor.
These addresses are not meaningful any more as soon as you exit the function (yes, a constructor is (also) a function.

You have different choice. 
First is to pass the arguments as pointers and not copying the values

```
sum(double* arg1, double* arg2) {
    this->argument_1 = arg1;
    this->argument_2 = arg2;
    cout << *this->argument_1 << " INSIDE CONSTR " << *this->argument_2 << "\n";
}
```

But actually, you don't need pointers at all in your case: just store the arguments as `double`, not `double*`

```
class binary_operation : public math_function {
public:
    double argument_1;
    double argument_2;
};
```

And change all the code in order to use `double` and not `double*` (easy, compiler will help you raising errors where old code is not valid any more)